# Transition instant set border, show slowly

Tags: html, css

Currently I have images as checkboxes which I can click then a yellow border comes up with transition.

Obviously it changes the margin stuff and everything when the border comes up so i set a default margin of `3px` wich goes away when the border is comming(the border is 3px too)
but since i used transition onto the border it grows up and while the border is growing all the images are shuttering and shaking :D

So now i would have to make the border be there instantly on 3px as soon as i klick it but it shouldnt instantly show as 3px...
i have no idea how to do that here's my current css

theres a little part of the css missing but stack overflow doesn't let me upload it because it doesn't accept it as code....

```css
    img{
        width: 100%;
        max-width: 380px;
        border: 3px solid rgba(255.0.0.0);
        background-color:black;
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 250px;
        margin: 3px;
        border-radius:15px;
        transition:opacity 2s ease, border 1s ease;
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/380x250" />
```

Comment: It's quite hard to really understand what you want. But you can always try adding `margin 1s ease` in the transition property. You shoul also show the css for `img:hover` or what ever is used to trigger the change.

Comment: You should read how to input code here - what I can see is you're missing indentation. *Any* code should start with 4 spaces to be interpreted as code.

Comment: add code to illustrate & clarify your q.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just have the border there as `transparent` and the just transition the ``border-color`?

```css
   img {
     width: 100%;
     max-width: 380px;
     border: 3px solid transparent;
     height: 100%;
     max-height: 250px;
     margin: 3px;
     border-radius: 15px;
     transition: opacity 2s ease, border-color 1s ease;
     opacity: 0.5;
   }
   img:hover {
     border-color: red;
   }
```

```html
<img src="http://placehold.it/200x200" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want not to break layout while adding border, you may consider using

> box-shadow

instead of border property, and transitioning this.

```js
$('.box').on('click', function() {
  $(this).addClass('box--checked');
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 120px;
  height: 120px;
  transition: box-shadow .3s linear;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  background-color: #DDD;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px darkorange;
}
.box--checked {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 6px darkorange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box box--one">A</div>
<div class="box box--two">B</div>
<div class="box box--three">C</div>
```